# I'm making webscraping program with python selenium. but I get error. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, stack-trace, backtrace

I'm making webscraping program with python selenium that shows my accademy homework when I just run this progra. but I get error

My full code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


delte = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/img[2]").click()


btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="logbtn"]').click()

loginid = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="webId"]').send_keys("I will not write my id and pw for safety")
loginpw = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="webPass"]').send_keys("")



loginbtn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/div/div/div[1]/a').click()


op = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="infobtn"]').click()


hw = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rightbox"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/a').click()
```

and I keep  getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response        
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)      
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
no such element: Unable 
to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="infobtn"]"}   
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.72)
Stacktrace: 
Backtrace:  
        Ordinal0 [0x00E5ACD3+2075859]
        Ordinal0 [0x00DEEE61+1633889]
        Ordinal0 [0x00CEB7BD+571325]        Ordinal0 [0x00D1AC2F+764975]        Ordinal0 [0x00D1AE1B+765467]        Ordinal0 [0x00D4D0F2+970994]        Ordinal0 [0x00D37364+881508]        Ordinal0 [0x00D4B56A+963946]        Ordinal0 [0x00D37136+880950]        Ordinal0 [0x00D0FEFD+720637]        Ordinal0 [0x00D10F3F+724799]        GetHandleVerifier [0x0110EED2+2769538]  
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01100D95+2711877]  
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEA03A+521194]   
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EE8DA0+516432]   
        Ordinal0 [0x00DF682C+1665068]
        Ordinal0 [0x00DFB128+1683752]
        Ordinal0 [0x00DFB215+1683989]
        Ordinal0 [0x00E06484+1729668]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76E5FEF9+25]     
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77477BBE+286]  
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77477B8E+238]
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It seems to be an error in the xpath not finding the path. See that in some cases you would have the ID, wouldn't it be better to locate such buttons or fields by the ID instead of the Xpath?
If it's not a private url, could you please share it for verification?

Comment: I think when you click, website loads something and script dont wait for the load

Comment: Try sleep() after clicks, or use implicity_wait and wait.until...

Comment: The tag is<a href="/myPolyLife/myPolyLife.do" class="ib sprite logbtn"></a>

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I put time.sleep(3) and it worked

Comment: Show us the HTML code with the element you are trying to click on

Comment: It's : <a href="/myPolyLife/myPolyLife.do" class="ib sprite logbtn"></a>